# Regex Capturing Group

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Say I have this dummy URL and I need to extract plants and their colors as `capture groups`

```
https://flowers.com/compare._plant1.green.402992_plant2.yellow.402228_plant3.red.403010_plant4.orange.399987.html
```

The following `regex` I have is capturing the elements I need as intended, but fails to capture anything when I have less than 4 plants in the URL. There a link to a regex tester at the bottom with sample code and URL that you can play with.

How do I modify this regex to work dynamically such that it captures what's available without requiring a static URL structure. For now, assume I am only capturing at most 4 plants (8 groups)

```
(flowers\.com)\/compare\._(?:([^.]+)\.([^.]+)).*_(?:([^.]+)\.([^.]+)).*_(?:([^.]+)\.([^.]+)).*_(?:([^.]+)\.([^.]+))
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/prjAO7/2

Comment: Make all of them optional except the first one https://regex101.com/r/psQUar/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the first plant and make the second, third and fourth one optional using a question mark non capturing group `(?:..)?`

Instead of using `.*` you might also match a dot and 1+ digits instead using `\.\d+` to prevent unnecessary backtracking.

```
(flowers\.com)\/compare\._([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.\d+(?:_([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.\d+)?(?:_([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.\d+)?(?:_([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.\d+)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZpOYrR/1)

---

Another option is to parse the url if you already know it is the `flowers.com` url and get the *path*. If the parts for the flowers are structured in the same way, you might also use a single part of the pattern `_([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.\d+`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/AcvWW9)

For example

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import re

pattern = r"_([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.\d+"

o = urlparse('https://flowers.com/compare._plant1.green.402992_plant2.yellow.402228_plant3.red.403010_plant4.orange.399987.html')
print(re.findall(pattern, o.path))
```

Output

```
[('plant1', 'green'), ('plant2', 'yellow'), ('plant3', 'red'), ('plant4', 'orange')]
```

Comment: Much much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

For any number of plants:

```
import re

url = 'https://flowers.com/compare._plant1.green.402992_plant2.yellow.402228_plant3.red.403010_plant4.orange.399987.html'
matches = re.finditer(r'(?:\d*_)([^.]+)\.([a-z]+)\.?', re.sub(r'.+\/flowers\.com\/compare\.', '', url))
for m in matches:
    print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

Sample output:

```
plant1 green
plant2 yellow
plant3 red
plant4 orange
```